# esp8266 soft AP displays the wrong name

Tags: arduino, esp8266

device: esp8266 (nodeMCU, esp-12E)
I have a esp8266 that previously run micropython on it. and now i wanted to return back to arduino programing.
using the example code on the docs:https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/soft-access-point-examples.html

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("setting up soft-AP");
  boolean result = WiFi.softAP("ESPsoftAP", "11234");
  if (result = true)
  {
    Serial.println("ready!");
    }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("failed!");
    
    }
  
  }

void loop(){
  Serial.printf("station connected = %d\n", WiFi.softAPgetStationNum());
  delay(3000);  
}
```

but the access point that shows up is named "MicroPython-7b15141" and the password does not work.
which to me seems like the line

```
boolean result = WiFi.softAP("ESPsoftAP", "11234");
```

was not able to do its function for some reason.
however on the serial monitor, the text "station connected = 0" does show.
so what went wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your sketch the Wifi parameters are not updated because the Wifi password is too short, therefore it keeps the previous ssid and password.
Try this, now it works: All the best:

boolean result = WiFi.softAP("ESPsoftAP", "1234567890")